# django 1.5.1 error DoesNotExist: MyModel matching query does not exist, but exists

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

My view:

```
try:
    id_osirix = int(request.POST.get('id'))
except ValueError:
    return HttpResponseBadRequest(_('ID is not numeric'))

instance = Osirix.objects.get(pk=id_osirix)      
url = instance.url 
instance.delete()    

# Reload MyModel code using url var
```

But I have this error: DoesNotExist: MyModel matching query does not exist. Lookup parameters were {u'id__exact': 3}

If I comment

```
#    url = instance.url
```

It works and it deletes the record.

MyModel classes definitions

```
# base/models.py
from django.db import models

class TimeStampedModel(models.Model):
    """
    An abstract base class model that provides selfupdating
    created and modified fields.
    """    
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

# apps/myapp/models.py
class OsirixType(models.Model):  
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, help_text=_('Standards list'))
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Osirix type")
        verbose_name_plural = _("OsirixType multiple types")

    # On Python 3: def __str__(self):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


# apps/myapp/models.py
class Osirix(TimeStampedModel):
    """    
    """
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    type = models.ForeignKey(OsirixType)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)        
    keywords = TaggableManager(_('Keywords'), blank=True, help_text=_('Commonly used word(s)'))
    operations = models.TextField(_('Operations'), blank=True)
    url = models.URLField(verbose_name=_("URL"))    
    version = models.CharField(        
        max_length=20,
        default='0.0.0',)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Osirix connection")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Osirix multiple connections")

    # On Python 3: def __str__(self):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    @property
    def ttd(self):
        from apps.fm.layers.models import Layer        
        return str(Layer.objects.filter(Osirix=self.id).aggregate(Avg('ttd'))['ttd__avg'])

    def keyword_list(self):
        keywords_qs = self.keywords.all()
        if keywords_qs:
            return ','.join([kw.name for kw in keywords_qs])
        else:
            return ''

@receiver(post_delete, sender=Osirix)
def osirix_post_delete_handler(sender, **kwargs):
    osirix = kwargs['instance']    
    osirix = os.path.join(THUMBNAILS_ROOT, str(osirix.pk // DATA_PARTITION), str(osirix.pk)) + '/'
    shutil.rmtree(osirix_thumbnail_root, ignore_errors=True)
```

It works as expected if I comment the previous line (url = instance.url)

Ideas? 
Is it correct the workflow?

Comment: can you show your `MyModel` ?

Comment: I'm going to update the question.

Comment: In which line do you get the error?

Comment: Thanks for the interest! But I found the problem after a couple of hours...I'm stupid! @receiver(post_delete, sender=Osirix) must be @receiver(pre_delete, sender=Osirix). Still don't understand why commenting url = instance.url was working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't see why commenting that line would make it work but you should catch that error anyway:

```
try:
    id_osirix = int(request.POST.get('id'))
except ValueError:
    return HttpResponseBadRequest(_('ID is not numeric'))

try:
    osirix = Osirix.objects.get(pk=id_osirix)
except Osirix.DoesNotExist:  # catch the DoesNotExist error
    osirix = None

if osirix:  # delete if only exists
    url = osirix.url
    osirix.delete()
```

Comment: Does this eliminate the problem totally?

Comment: I removed the DB tables and I run syncdb --migrate and the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar type of problem. it took me while to figure this out. It seems when you try to match certain data with the database, make sure compare only specific data which table and field are available in your compared database.in Django(4.2) when you make ‘request.POST’ call, it will bring csrf@token along with your expected data.

something like this:

**in view**

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    for info in request.POST:
        key = info
        value = request.POST[key]

        print(key, value)
```

**output**

```
csrfmiddlewaretoken 8FLnD2a1fGi8fNDJFZrNs28x3y0xOSqb1T(csrf@token)
expected_key_01 expected_value_01
expected_key_02 expected_value_02
```

this extra csrf@token clash with database as there is no field to store or match with this data. thats why often program throw back ' matching query does not exist.' error.

to simply solve this, we just have to remove extra data which coming with 'request.POST' method.

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
      for info in request.POST:
        key = info
        value = request.POST[key]

     
        try:  
            if key == 'expected_value1' or key == 'expected_value2':
               my_variable = MyModel.objects.get(check_01__exact=key, check_02__exact=value)

               ## other code ##
        except:
              pass
```

removing extra piece of data will solve this problem.